# Side Navigation Bar won't repeat?

Tags: css

I'm working on a website, and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the side navigation bar to repeat. Because the bar is floating, I've created an image and told it to repeat. But it won't. Am I missing a step?

Here is the code for the bar:

```
#leftColumn {
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:30px;
    background:url(http://www.cnam.ca/uploads/images/left-column2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

You can check out the problem at this website http://www.cnam.ca/annual-workshop

Comment: because the image is a solid color, why not use a color code (e.g. `#00FFEE`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the #leftColumn element in Chrome developer tools, I see that the issue is with the height of the div, not the background-image.  Your div height is only as tall as it requires to contain all the content.  Adding *height: 600px* to that element confirms this, as the background image repeats.

You should look into faux-columns to achieve the result you're looking for.
http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns